# java: Unable to implement Repository method: PersonRepository.save(Object entity). No possible implementations found

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm making a small endpoint and it doesn't work for me. It is very simple, and for this I am using micronaut

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.autentia</groupId>
    <artifactId>autentia</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.3.4</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>com.autentia.Application</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>3.2.2</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.autentia</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=autentia</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My repository:

```
import com.prueba.entity.Person;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

My entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

}
```

Finally, the error

**java: Unable to implement Repository method: PersonRepository.findById(Object id). Cannot query entity [Person] on non-existent property: Id**

What can I be doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: maybe lombok is causing the problem .. looks like he did not find the @Id where its expected

Comment: have you tried naming your field `id` (all lower case) instead of `Id` with a capital letter I?

Comment: Also, +1 to the "It's probably Lombok" tally

Comment: And also +1 to "have you tried naming your field id" and "maybe lombok is causing the problem". Lombok annotations should be listed first.

Comment: I have removed the lombok annotation and used getters and setters and now I get a new error....
This is: java: Unable to implement Repository method: PersonRepository.delete(Object entity). Delete all not supported for entities with no ID
I don't find as much information about micronaut as if I find it with spring boot

Comment: I tried renaming field Id to id (all lowercase) and i have new error... 
`Caused by: Unexpected error loading bean definition 
 $Repository.PersonRepository$Intercepted$Definition]: failed to access class Repository.PersonRepository$Intercepted from class $Repository.PersonRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference (Repository.PersonRepository$Intercepted and $Repository.PersonRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference are in unnamed module of loader 'app') at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinitionReference.isPresent(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinitionReference.java:165)`

Comment: When I'm jumping into new stuff, I usually clone a working repo and play with it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide should help you in creating your first Micronaut JDBC application.

https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-jdbc-repository-maven-java.html

If you would like to use Lombok add it as a feature when you use either Micronaut CLI or Micronaut Launch.

There are other [guides](https://micronaut.io/guides/) and [documentation](https://micronaut.io/docs/) that should help you on your journey.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should download or create micronaut project with Lombok dependency selected, so that you won't run into this issue.

***But here is the guide if you want to add lombok later on in the project.***

All you need to do is, **add dependencies in correct order**.
The order of annotations processors seems to play important role here.
Use these dependencies as mentioned below.

Note: This answer is based on gradle, but the concept should also work with Maven

**Step-1:** Use this below lombok annotation processor as the first thing in dependencies:

```
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
```

**Step-2:** Then after annotation processors, use lombok compile time dependency:

```
compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
```

**Step-3:** Then you can write your rest of the dependencies:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
...
...
```

**build.gradle** (dependencies section)

```
dependencies {

    /* Step 1 */
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")

    /* Step 2 */
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    /* Step 3 */
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway")
    implementation("io.micronaut.oraclecloud:micronaut-oraclecloud-atp")
    implementation("io.micronaut.oraclecloud:micronaut-oraclecloud-sdk")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue a while ago,

It worked fine for me, after I created **get** methods instead of using ***@Getter*** of *lombok* and worked every time for me.

This conflict occurs because ***JPA*** uses ***@Column*** and ***@Id*** to map the fields in entity to columns in the database. When Lombok generates getters for these fields, it interferes with the ***JPA*** mapping and occurs error.